# POCO - Flatten or Use Complex Types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, poco, cqrs, complextype

I am using POCOs as my model classes in a ASP.Net MVC project. So far this is working well, but in most cases these POCOs contain simple types. I now have a situation where I am considering using some complex types and I am not sure about the benefits of this approach. Further my situation is complicated by the fact that I need to split a single database table into multiple POCOs. The following example will explain. I have an employee table with about 40 fields. I don't want to always be passing around this large object with all its properties so I created 3 POCO classes that represent logical groupings of the data as follows:

```
public class EmployeeProfile
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }        
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    etc ...    
}

public class EmployeeContact
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber Phone { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class EmploymentInfo
{
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }       
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    etc ....
}
```

So far so good, however I also at times do need the entire employee table as a single object and that is where I am unsure. I could create the employee class by putting the other types in it like so:

```
public class EmployeeDetail
{
    public EmployeeProfile EmployeeProfile { get; set; }
    public EmployeeContact EmployeeContact { get; set; }
    public EmploymentInfo EmploymentInfo { get; set; }        

}
```

or I could copy all the properties individual properties of the three POCOs including the complex types contained therein into the EmployeeDetail class so that it is flat, with simple properties like so:

```
public class EmployeeDetail
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }        
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    etc ...        
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber Phone { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }       
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    etc ....

}
```

aside from the fact that the version containing complex types will take a shorter time to create the POCO, what are the benefits of using one approach over another? I get the idea that the whole point is to be object oriented, but I'm not sure if in this case there is any benefit to "nesting" these objects. It seems to me like there will be more work accessing the nested objects and translating them back and forth between my view model and domain model.

**Edit:** I would like to point out that the sub-models I am considering are not specific to a particular view. They are likely to be used multiple places throughout the application. This is an HR/Employee Benefits app. I need these classes to be reusable otherwise I would just put them in a ViewModel, which I am already using.

Answer (score 0):

What you in fact want to do is to divide your business concept `Employee` into 3 parts, based on the views where they will be used. So you want to split it into `EmployeeProfile` to show it in the view connected with e.g. profile management, etc.

By doing so you mix the business domain with your view domain - and this is something you should avoid.

Splitting your domain models is a good solution in case there is a logical domain split + there is a high potential that certain parts will be needed separately. So a good example might be (although not neccesarily in every case) defining a separate domain model for the `Address` of an `Employee`.

What I would do if I were in your shoes:

- I would leave a domain model `Employee` without splitting it into view-related parts.
- I would create separate view models based on which part of `Employee` model data I need on a certain view.
- I would think if I could split the `Employee` model into some domain-related submodels (like e.g. separating the Address from `Employee`).

From the performance perspective the above solution can also be of a benefit. Sending several additional fields from and to the database is not such a big hassle, whereas the need to JOIN your submodels in case you need the whole one can be in some cases harmful to your performance (especially if there are thousands of employees).

What is more: from the maintaibility perspective I would also recommend to use the above solution. Using too many nested objects when it is not really proper from the domain perspective can introduce some additional challenges with e.g. CRUD operations (for example there will be a need to provide a commit/rollback mechanisms when saving/updating the whole `Employee` etc) .

Comment: I am already using ViewModels. My point is not that I need the "submodels" for views, but the fact that I don't want to be passing around this 40 property class all the time. I think it is quite legitimate to consider a portion of the Employee model as a legitimate aspect of the domain model. Where does it say that only "whole" entities should be in the domain?

Comment: I have updated my answer with additional explanations.

Comment: There is no need for model joining in my scenario because that is done in the DAL. I am using SQL queries to fill my objects. So all the properties I need come from one query and I fill the sub models all at once.

Comment: I edited my question. One reason for the split model is re-usabilty. I need the individual classes in may places not just for one specific view. This fits with the part of your answer that mentions sub-models make sense when there is a high potential that certain parts will be needed separately. This is indeed the case and I did not make that clear in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

@bejger has a great answer, but I wanted to add a bit that's a little to long for a comment.

Dividing up your data is a bad idea. It doesn't matter if your table holds 40 properties or 400, you're always best served querying a single table than doing joins. Now, there's caveats to what I just said. Logical groupings of data that can be reused should be broken out. Things like an address make more sense being composed into a class that needs that information than repeated over and over.

With composition, though, you have two options:

1. **Complex Type**: Complex types allow you to abstract a set of properties that you want to use on multiple classes, but at the end of the day, each table gets its own copy of those properties. This has the benefit that you don't need to employ joins to access the data, but it has the limitation that you cannot include foreign keys or other navigation properties.
2. **Foreign Key**: Using a foreign key lets you have one table to hold all instances of this property group. Again, the downside is a join is required. This is really only suitable option if you could forsee interacting with *just* these properties, or you need a one-to-many collection of them. Using the example of an address, if you want to be able to just pull all addresses without worrying about the employee association or you want to be able to assign a variable number of addresses to the employee, then this is a viable option.

Other than that, don't worry about your table size. Even a table with tons of columns is still more efficient than a join, and if you only need a subset of those columns you can simply select the ones you need (you can do this in LINQ with the `Select` method, which Entity Framework will honor when querying the database).

Comment: Please look at my edit. These are indeed re-uasble sub-models that are required in many places in my application. That was not clear in my original question.

Comment: Then, you have your answer. See my guidance about whether to employ a complex type or a foreign key, but you'll need one or the other if you want to reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, instead of splitting my domain model classes into sub-components, I took a totally different approach and opted for separating my Read model from my Domain Model, or to put it another way separating the R from the CUD. The reason I am doing so is because 65-75% of my application is about reading and reporting on data, not creating, updating or deleting it.

So in this case I would have as my domain entity the full Employee model with no composition:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }        
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    etc ...        
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber Phone { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }       
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    etc ....
}
```

In addition to this on the Read side I might have for example the following:

```
public class EmployeeRoster
{
    public int EmployeeID { get;set;}
    public string FullName { get;set; }   
    public decimal Salary { get;set; }       
    public string Occupation { get;set;}
    public DateTime DateOfHire { get;set;}
}
```

and whatever other objects I need on the read side. This sounds a lot like CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation) and I have been aware of CQRS for some time, but the resources I've seen on CQRS have been disappointing. For example, it is often suggested that one use a different database for read operations vs writes. While I understand why one might want to do that (performance), for my purposes that is overkill at this point. Further, most resources on CQRS suggest that read queries be mapped directly to view models. I have a few problems with that. One, in many cases I need to reuse these read models. Something like EmployeeRoster is used in multiple places in my application for different purposes. Also, there are cases where I need to apply business logic on my read objects before they are consumed by the view model.

To sum it up, at this point I am certain I need a separate read model, but I am not necessarily convinced that CQRS as it is formally practiced is the way to go. So I have answered my own question at this point, but have not accepted this as my answer because I think other people with more experience with separate read models and/or CQRS could provide a better answer than me.